# 3D CSS Transform - transform:rotateX(180deg);

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I'm trying to animate an image on hover by flipping it upside-down (180 deg) along the x-axis.

Just like [**here**](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/#css3dtransforms)

Except I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
img {
    transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}

img:hover {
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

Comment: @JezenThomas current chrome stable. the demos all work on the referenced page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), Chrome still needs the `-webkit` prefix.

You're missing the browser prefix.

```
img {
    -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

This also means that you'll need to add in the other browser prefixes for their respective browsers. If you would rather not mess around with browser prefixes, you can use a plugin called [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) by Lea Verou to take care of it all for you.